# Why is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException sometimes not handled?

Tags: java, spring, netty, project-reactor

Hi I am using reactive elasticsearch client something like this:

```java
reactiveClient.bulk(bulkRequest)
.retryWhen(
            Retry.backoff(
                retryConfig.getMaxAttempts(),
                retryConfig.getMinBackoff()
            )
                .jitter(retryConfig.getJitter())
                .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> log.warn(
                    "Failed to index. Retrying.",
                    retrySignal.failure()
                ))
                .onRetryExhaustedThrow(
                    (retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> {
                      log.error(
                          "Failed to index {} times. Giving up.",
                          retryBackoffSpec.maxAttempts,
                          retrySignal.failure()
                      );
                      return retrySignal.failure();
                    }
                )
        )
        .onErrorResume(BulkRequestFailedException.class, ex -> processError(ex, tasksToProcess))
        .onErrorResume(Exception.class, ex -> processError(ex, tasksToProcess));
```

Everything work fine most of the time logging warning like this:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST http://esn01.app:9200/_bulk?timeout=1m [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:70)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:224)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:273)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:413)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:250)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:97)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:189)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onUncaughtException(HttpClientConnect.java:358)
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onUncaughtException(ReactorNetty.java:647)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:214)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:462)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:233)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:454)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:485)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:127)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.readTimedOut(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:98)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.channelIdle(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:90)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$ReaderIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:503)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AbstractIdleTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:475)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:391)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null
```

with the mentioned log message from our code. But sometimes the error gets logged by `reactor.core.publisher.Operators` as "Operator called default onErrorDropped" with stacktrace like this:

```
    

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST http://esn03.app:9200/_bulk?timeout=1m [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:70)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:224)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:273)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:413)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:250)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:97)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:189)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onUncaughtException(HttpClientConnect.java:358)
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onUncaughtException(ReactorNetty.java:647)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:214)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:462)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:233)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:454)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:485)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:127)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.readTimedOut(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:98)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.channelIdle(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:90)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$ReaderIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:503)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AbstractIdleTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:475)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:394)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null
```

with only difference being line `at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:394)`
but this error ignores all the error handlers.

This happens when there are lot of request timeouting.

Any idea whats happening here and how to fix it?

Using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.4.5 that means io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:1.0.6. Java 11.